# Send local notification after termination app swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

Is is possible to perform some specific task after some specific time when app state goes to terminate/not running state.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    print("APP in background state") // Working fine
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "backService", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

But when app state goes to terminate state then its not working?

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
     NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "backService", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

I also tried

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

    let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    self.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
    application.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { 
                    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "backService", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

schedule a local notification, cancel and reschedule as long as your app is running

then if it is closed, the notification isn't cancelled anymore and will fire!

Comment: Notification will fire i agreed but i want to trigger after some specific time on terminate state.Not at a time of terminating state.

Comment: "Send local notification after termination app swift 2" ;) thats the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually scheduling a notification... When you create a new notification locally, which can be done in the `applicationWillTerminate` method, there's a property called `fireDate` which you can set to have the notification get sent whenever you want to.

Comment: Notification send at the time of terminating but I want to send after some specific time while app in terminating state.

Comment: Then set the fire date to whatever arbitrary time you desire. That's the whole point of that property.